# progress related problem in android using Threading!

Tags: android, progress-bar

friends,

i am using following code to display progress on andorid activity when i call web service method to getposts it show progress. but when call of serivce is complete my application gets crashed.

please guide what mistake am i doing or any other alternative way to achieve this goal?

```
mProgressStatus = 0;
  Thread th=new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    if (mProgressStatus < 100) {
     myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
     myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
   }

  });


    th.start();

  results = p.GetPosts(p, PageSize, adap.getCount());

  mProgressStatus=100;
```

th.stop();

Comment: Try creating the progress bar inside the new thread instead.

Answer (score 0):

So, if your application crashes, maybe you should look at the error message first? Or at least provide it for us.

(A tip: I read three posts of you today and you always have trouble with the first/last lines of your code pasting, please check you code pasting before you submit a question...)

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1519): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using runOnUiThread, if you are in an activity class

```
mProgressStatus = 0;
    MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {});
        public void run() {
            if (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
   });
```

Everything about the UI have to be executed in the UI Thread